# How to remove search.practicalsprint.com from my chrome

Tags: google-chrome

[I cannot remove this malicious page which redirects me to Yahoo ,from my chrome ,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Hxt.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same tedious issue after installing macafee web advisor. Open chrome -> settings -> type in the search "default search" -> change search engine used in the address bar from secure search to google, things shall go back to normal .

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Did your chrome window crash before this happened? If so, go to chrome settings and change your search engine back to google.